# Is it possible to let mac remember the desktops and webpages each one opend?

Tags: macos, desktop

Is it possible to let mac remember the desktops and webpages each one opend?

in my case, I use 5 desktops to open 5 web pages, it's convenient for me to work.
[image]

you know after reboot my macos, them will disappear. so, is there a way to save my config?

Comment: The history in the browser will be a start.

Comment: The browser should remember the open windows & pages, but Spaces will not remember where you put them. Spaces is not designed to have any app spread to more than one screen.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. From my experience with Safari, macOS can indeed remember after reboot the specific space a window was placed on, but you need to check "Reopen windows when logging back in". What is your web browser (from your screenshot, it looks like Chrome or Edge)?

Comment: @jaume no matter the browser, if need safari I use safari, if need chrome, I can use chrome. so, is it possible to create a script for making  it?

Comment: I don't think you need a script, as I've said, it works, but I have to check the option to reopen windows when logging back in when I reboot or shut down my Mac. I'm on Monterey, what version of macOS do you have? When rebooting, do you check the option I mention?